# Is there a way in VS 2010 to add a reference to an assembly that is only in your GAC?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, assemblies, gac

Right clicking on project and clicking "Add Reference..." does not provide a way to do this.  The .Net tab doesn't look in the GAC and if you browse to C:\windows\assembly you are presented with the actual directory structure of the GAC.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no way to do this by navigating with explorer.  I do share the frustration here as I've run into the same problem.  The way I work around this is to do the following

- Open up CMD
- Navigate through c:\windows\assembly to find the find the assembly in question
- Copy the path to the clip board
- Open up the Add Reference dialog and paste in the path

Or just copy the DLL into a temporary directory and navigate to that through the Add Reference dialog.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'm going to leave question open for a little bit more to see if anyone else has any ideas.  Gracias.